# C# Excel Interop VSTO Add-In Foreach/If statement

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, vsto, excel-interop

I'm relatively new to coding in C#, having done most of my excel automation with macros. I'm trying to move most of the automation we use to a VSTO add-in for everyone to easily use. I have the below code that basically looks at C2 and if it matches a predefined variable, writes a specific variable into E2 and then moves down the E columns (C3 for E3, etc.). The code below works just fine, I'm just curious if there is an easier way to write this? I can create the foreach statement for each predefined variable, but I figured someone may know an easier way to combine all of the different variables under 1 if statement.

```
           string morphine15ml = "6510005510209015";
           string lorazepam30ml = "57100060001320";

           int rowNum = 1;
           foreach (Range packageSize in xlWS.Range["C2:C" + xlWSlastRow].Cells)
           {
               rowNum++;

               if (packageSize.Value == morphine15ml)
               {
                   foreach (Excel.Range columnE in xlWS.Range["E" + rowNum].Cells)
                   {
                       columnE.Value = "15";
                   }
               }
               else if (packageSize.Value == lorazepam30ml)
               {
                   foreach (Excel.Range columnE in xlWS.Range["E" + rowNum].Cells)
                   {
                       columnE.Value = "30";
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   foreach (Excel.Range columnE in xlWS.Range["E" + rowNum].Cells)
                   {
                       columnE.Value = "1";
                   }
               }
```

Comment: A proper [mcve] would make it easier to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Also what version of C# are you targetting?

Comment: Sounds like you are interested in using the `switch` expression instead of multiple if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this code by using [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements) - note that loops are the same except for the value assigned to `columnE.Value`, so you can calculate it beforehand and use:

```cs
const string morphine15ml = "6510005510209015";
const string lorazepam30ml = "57100060001320";
int rowNum = 1;
foreach (Range packageSize in xlWS.Range["C2:C" + xlWSlastRow].Cells)
{
    rowNum++;
    var value = packageSize.Value switch
    {
        morphine15ml => "15",
        lorazepam30ml => "30",
        _ => "1"
    };
    foreach (Excel.Range columnE in xlWS.Range["E" + rowNum].Cells)
    {
        columnE.Value = value;
    }
}
```

If [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) are not supported in the language version used then you can rewrite it to switch statement:

```cs
string value;
switch (packageSize.Value)
{
    case morphine15ml:
        value = "15";
        break;
    case lorazepam30ml:
        value = "30";
        break;
    default:
        value = "1";
        break;
}
```